# Win32API Mouse vs Real Mouse Click

Tags: python, winapi

I have recently started using win32api to simulate mouse events and was wondering if it was at all detectable?

For example, does the api follow the exact same process/run the exact same commands as if done when using a real mouse - or are there some slight differences which can be detected? Furthermore, is this the same case with win32com SendKeys (via Shell Script/Python)?

I ask, because in the past I have had a few applications detect the Java robot library - but they all seem to work fine when using the Python win32api. Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that some "bot finding" applications will look for specific signatures of known programs, similar to AV, if the Java robot library is well know it may well be that the applications finding your program are looking for that libraries signature, wheres the Python win32api will not have such as signature, on top of that, I don't know much of the Java robot library, but it may be that it sends messages directly to the application window, rather than through mouse control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function will insert input events into the same queue as a hardware device but the events are marked with a [`LLMHF_INJECTED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx) flag that can be detected by hooks. To avoid this flag you probably have to write a custom driver.