# Press key to game window with Python

Tags: python, events, keyboard

I try to pass keyboard event to game window but it doesn't work. For another program such as Notepad++ it is works.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.release('a')
```

The same a problem I have with mouse events. I tried use "Mouse and Keyboard Recorder" program and it work. Which is a problem?

I try to write bot to game for fun.

Answer (score 0):

It's my answer:

[Win32API Mouse vs Real Mouse Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929744/win32api-mouse-vs-real-mouse-click/44931001#44931001)

But I don't know how to write a custom driver :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).